# Is there any way to embed a pdf file into an html5 page?

Tags: ios, html, pdf

I want to have a web page coded with HTML5, and I want to be able to put a pdf file onto this page so you can view it without having to click on any links to download it separately. Anyone know how to do this?
I want it to keep the text, images, and layout of the pdf file also. If that weren't the case I would just use an image. Thanks!

Edit: This will be hopefully going onto the ipad. So it won't support adobe. I need to just find a way to somehow make the pdf file show up in an html5 page without using a viewer. I want to keep all of its layers. It doesn't have to stay a pdf file when its on the page, I just need to find a way to transfer all of those layers there without having to do this manually with divs for each image, paragraph, etc.

Comment: [This link](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/2007/08/using_the_html_embed_tag_to_di.html) may be of use to you.

Comment: [pdf.js](https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js) renders a PDF in HTML5. No plugins required [Example](http://people.mozilla.org/~gal/test.html)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible without using Flash. Instead, you might want to convert the PDF to a different format (HTML for example) that can be rendered by the browser. There are tools that can do this from the command line, so making a script to do it on your site won't be too difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the embed tag like this:

```
<embed src="/path/to/your/file.pdf" />
```

Comment: This works a bit, but not well. You need to specify width/height, but this only controls the container and the PDF doesn't scale to fill the area.

Comment: you can get the pdf to fit like this:
<embed src="/path/to/your/file.pdf#view=Fit" />

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could convert the pdf to images on the server and display the images instead of the original pdf. As far as i know, Apache pdfbox can be used to do such a convert.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late and maybe issuu is gonna fix it soon but for now you can embed with issuu.com using an iframe and your magazine address ending in ?mode=mobile. Tested in ipad:

```
<iframe width="850px" height="580px" src="http://www.issuu.com/your_username/docs/your_magazine_name?mode=mobile" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I would like same mobile version loading in desktop so there is no advertising. If you know how to make the browser to think it's an ipad let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This code would directly embed a pdf viewer in a webpage

```
<object data="path to pdf " type="application/pdf" width="100" height="100">
  <p>Alternative text - include a link <a href="path to pdf">to the PDF!</a></p>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET, [this link](http://portal.activepdf.com/Demos/PortalinaniPad.aspx) may be of interest to you.

> Browser Based PDF Viewing And Editing
>   Hosted entirely on your server,
>   activePDF Portal is an ASP.NET
>   WebControl that enables your users to
>   interactively view and modify PDF
>   documents from any source - adding
>   comments, form fields, bookmarks, and
>   more – directly from within a standard
>   web browser, without requiring any
>   client-side software such as Adobe
>   Reader or Flash, or the use of ActiveX
>   controls.
>   - http://portal.activepdf.com/

Answer (score -1):

[PDFObject](https://github.com/pipwerks/PDFObject) looks promising, but it doesn't work on iPads at the moment.

Comment: Don't think this would work on WinRT as the pdfobject.js file in github seems to assume an ActiveXObject which WinRT won't allow