# Is there any way to open pdf file inside web app,without using phonegap

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to open pdf file inside a html5 app without using phonegap, any thoughts or ideas would be a guiding light for my development...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to embed a pdf file into an html5 page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113334/is-there-any-way-to-embed-a-pdf-file-into-an-html5-page)

Comment: Is there anyway to open instead of an iframe in html page any plugin that would actually open inside the app and would not let content go out....

Comment: What does that mean, "not let content go out"?!

Comment: I mean that opening in any new tab or such would'nt help my cause...

Comment: In using phoengap and html5 app we can do this using inappbrowser, any other suggestion is what i'm looking for any help would great...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried PDF.JS ?

Take a look at this. It would solve you problem.

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/
Sample: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

Comment: Ventura thanks for ur suggestion but this would not work in ie and safari i believe...